# Installing common library seems to install additional node_modules within the library

Tags: reactjs, rollupjs

### Overview

I have created a common react library to be used within a range of applications. I had no issues with it prior to upgrading on of the applications to React 18.

I am using rollup to do the library configuration and the library also has a documentation site.

### Issue

When I download the package from artifacts it seems fine and works but when I install the package it seems to create a node_modules folder within the library and install an older version of React.

This causes a React version mismatch error and stops the app from running until I manually delete the node_modules folder, it then runs correctly without issue.

Additionally this behaviour doesn't happen in a different application we have which is running React 17.0.2, it seems to only have become an issue in our React 18 apps.

#### Example

Here you can see that the package has it's own version of React installed which doesn't exist when I download the package directly from artifacts.

[image]

### Rollup configuration

The library is running React 18 and so is the application and we use Rollup to do the library configuration.

```js
export default {
  input: './src/lib/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
      preserveModules: false
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
      preserveModules: false
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      tsconfigOverride: {
        exclude: [
          '**/__tests__',
          '**/*.test.ts',
          '**/*.test.tsx',
          './src/tests',
          './src/examples',
          '**/*.example.ts',
          '**/*.example.tsx',
          '**/ApplicationRouter.tsx',
          '**/index.tsx'
        ],
        include: ['src/lib']
      }
    }),
    postcss({
      extract: true,
      minimize: true,
      use: [
        ['sass', {
          includePaths: [
            './src/lib',
            './node_modules'
          ]
        }]
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the npm version causing the problem. If you are using npm `>=v7` try to install the dependencies with

```bash
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

And see if that solves the problem.

Also, I see you are creating a React Component Library, there's a tool [Create React Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@haseebanwar/create-react-package) lets you do this with Rollup, Babel, ESLint, TypeScript, and PostCSS already set up. So you can focus on the code rather than configuration.

Comment: This seems to have worked, but I am curious if there is a better way to configure rollup to avoid needing to do this

Comment: It happens because, with npm >=v7, the npm tries to install peer dependencies automatically and if a package you're installing mismatches the version of React, it fails. The only solution is to use npm with `--legacy-peer-deps` or use npm 6, or the authors of the libraries manage peer dependencies in a better way. Or better you can use the tool I listed in the answer